# How to profile multithreaded clojure results with Tufte

Tags: clojure, profiling

[Tutfe](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tufte) is a profiling library which is a great fit for understanding the composition of runtime, especially in complicated call stacks.

When I ran it in my project, a section of code I expected to be performance-expensive didn't register as a high-offender in the results, which led to the discovery that Tufte (reasonably) had only captured the thread-local results.

The docs indicate that it has built-in binding to instrument accumulated time on other threads using the `{:dynamic? true}` option, but there appears to be more needed in order to capture the time accumulated on other threads, such as those initiated by `pmap`

Here's the original Tufte demo, with some multithreading introduced:

```
(require '[taoensso.tufte :as tufte :refer (defnp p profiled profile)])

;; We'll request to send `profile` stats to `println`:
(tufte/add-basic-println-handler! {})

;;; Let's define a couple dummy fns to simulate doing some expensive work
(defn get-x [] (Thread/sleep 500)             "x val")
(defn get-y []
  (pmap
    #(do
        (Thread/sleep 500)
        (print %))
    (range 10)))

;; How do these fns perform? Let's check:

(profile ; Profile any `p` forms called during body execution
  {:dynamic? true} ; Profiling options; we'll use the defaults for now
  (dotimes [_ 5]
    (p :get-x (get-x))
    (p :get-y (get-y))))
```

The output indicates that the println statements forced the threads to evaluate. And yet, the get-y accumulated time does not show up in the results:

```
2187306594=> nil
=> #{:basic-println}
=> #'user/get-x
=> #'user/get-y
8904365271703695842110783956243415760829=> nil

       pId      nCalls       Min        Max       MAD      Mean   Time% Time
    :get-x           5  500.52ms   504.84ms    1.44ms  502.44ms     100 2.51s
    :get-y           5   90.67μs   581.91μs   162.2μs  269.29μs       0 1.35ms
Clock Time                                                          100 2.51s
Accounted Time                                                      100 2.51s
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer: lazy initialization. Though the data was being printed to the screen, it was the end of the `(profile...)` form that was doing it, outside of the spied-upon form `get-y`.

This would yield the same effect:

```
(profile ; Profile any `p` forms called during body execution
  {:dynamic? true} ; Profiling options; we'll use the defaults for now
  (dotimes [_ 5]
    (p :get-x (get-x))
    (doall (p :get-y (get-y)))))

30167894521045768392530798241651268940371023657894=> nil

           pId      nCalls       Min        Max       MAD      Mean   Time% Time
        :get-x           5  500.07ms   504.58ms    1.41ms  503.08ms      50 2.52s
        :get-y           5   80.25μs   126.18μs   15.98μs  104.84μs       0 524.18μs
    Clock Time                                                          100 5.03s
Accounted Time                                                           50 2.52s
```

Whereas this one realizes the lazy sequences inside the get-y profile:

```
(profile ; Profile any `p` forms called during body execution
  {:dynamic? true} ; Profiling options; we'll use the defaults for now
  (dotimes [_ 5]
    (p :get-x (get-x))
    (p :get-y (doall (get-y)))))

12037645987105892436354169872031089546721058729634=> nil

           pId      nCalls       Min        Max       MAD      Mean   Time% Time
        :get-x           5  502.54ms   504.71ms   705.6μs   503.5ms      50 2.52s
        :get-y           5  501.69ms   505.68ms    1.05ms  503.06ms      50 2.52s
    Clock Time                                                          100 5.03s
Accounted Time                                                          100 5.03s
```

This is important to know for the profiling experience, because when dealing with lazy sequences, you're realizing the performance of how they are used, not the sequences themselves:

```
(profile ; Profile any `p` forms called during body execution
  {:dynamic? true} ; Profiling options; we'll use the defaults for now
  (dotimes [_ 5]
    (p :get-x (get-x))
    (p ::realize-y
       (doall (p :get-y (get-y))))))

06538947123410695278450678913223071958645126380479=> nil

            pId      nCalls       Min        Max       MAD      Mean   Time% Time
:user/realize-y           5  503.29ms   504.86ms  458.12μs  504.37ms      50 2.52s
         :get-x           5  500.13ms   505.06ms     1.4ms  503.64ms      50 2.52s
         :get-y           5    86.0μs     1.15ms  331.81μs  322.94μs       0 1.61ms
     Clock Time                                                          100 5.04s
 Accounted Time                                                          100 5.04s
```